# Creating WCF service by determining type at runtime

Tags: wcf, service, runtime

I am trying to create a WCF service without knowing its type/interface at runtime.  To do this, I use ChannelFactory.  ChannelFactory is a generic class so I need to use Type.MakeGenericType.  The type I pass to MakeGenericType is from a list of interfaces I previously gathered with reflection by searching some assemblies.

Ultimately, I call MethodInfo.Invoke to create the object.  The object is created just fine, but I cannot cast it to the proper interface.  Upon casting, I receive the following error:

"Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 'Tssc.Services.MyType.IMyType'"

After some experimenting, I have found that the interface/type passed to MakeGenericType seems to be the problem.  If I substitute the interface in my list with the actual interface, then everything works fine.  I have combed through the two objects and cannot see a difference.  When I modify the code to produce both types, comparing them with Equals returns false.  It is unclear to me whether Equals is just checking that they are referring to the same object (not) or thety are checking all properties, etc.

Could this have something to do with how I gathered my interfaces (Reflection, saving in a list...)?  A comparison of the objects seems to indicate they are equivalent.  I printed all properties for both objects and they are the same.  Do I need to dig deeper?  If so, into where?

```
         // createService() method

     //*** tried both of these interfaces, only 2nd works - but they seem to be identical
     //Type t = interfaces[i]; // get type from list created above - doesn't work
     Type t = typeof(Tssc.Services.MyType.IMyType); // actual type - works OK

     // create ChannelFactory type with my type parameter (t)
     Type factoryType = typeof(ChannelFactory<>);
     factoryType = factoryType.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { t });         

     // create ChannelFactory<> object with two-param ctor
     BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
     string address = "blah blah blah";
     var factory = Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType, new object[] { binding, address });

     // get overload of ChannelFactory<>.CreateChannel with no parameters
     MethodInfo method = factoryType.GetMethod("CreateChannel", new Type[] { });

     return method.Invoke(factory, null);

     //--------------- code that calls code above and uses its return

     object ob = createService();

     //*** this cast fails
     Tssc.Services.MyType.IMyType service = (Tssc.Services.MyType.IMyType)ob;
```

Comment: It would be useful to get t.ToString() (after t = interfaces[i]) and ob.GetType().ToString() (after object ob = createService()) - this might give us a clue as to why this isn't working.

Comment: Tried that, but ToString didn't tell me much. I examined the contents of the working (hard-code) and non-working (from interfaces[]) versions of 't' and found that the only difference is the TypeHandle property.

Comment: The 2 interfaces have to be exactly the same - the to string should give you the namespace and type name of exactly the same interface. If they aren't the same it wont work.

Comment: The ToString indeed gives the namespace/type.  They are the same.  Therefore, I dumped the remaining properties of both versions of the type and found that the only difference was the TypeHandle property.  What might cause the TypeHandle to be different if all else is the same?

Comment: I think the TypeHandle is always going to be different - its a unique internal point to the data structure. What happens if instead of Type t = interfaces[i] you try Type t = Type.GetType(interfaces[i].ToString())

Comment: Type.GetType returns null.

Comment: That's really odd! How are you populating your interfaces array - is it happening in the same AppDomain?

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand AppDomains.  I populate my list (as described below) in a separate method in the same console app. 

I am using System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile to search assemblies in a known folder.  In each assembly I look for interfaces with the service attribute System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute.  I save those interfaces (types) in a list (interfaces[]).

Comment: Right ok that makes sense - and those assemblies aren't referenced in your console application?

Comment: Correct.  The point is to discover them at runtime.  In general, the overall goal is to be able to add/remove services without constantly updating some master list, hard-coding types...  Hence, all the creating types at runtime, etc.

Comment: So the bit where you're doing your cast (Tssc.Services.MyType.IMyType service = (Tssc.Services.MyType.IMyType)ob;) where does Tssc.Services.MyType.IMyType reside?

Comment: Ah.  The code that reads the assemblies, puts together the types, and creates the service channel is in a separate assembly (Utils) from the console app.  Along with Utils, the console app has a reference to yet another assembly (Support) that contains the interface in question (IMyType).  The cast is in the console app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I understand whats happening here - the problem is relating to loading the same assembly being effectively loaded twice - once via a reference, and once via the assembly load command. What you need to do is change the place where you load your assembly, and check to see if it already exists in the current AppDomain, like this maybe:

```
Assembly assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetName().Name.Equals("ClassLibrary1Name"));

if (assembly == null)
{
    assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile("path to your assembly");
}

//do your work here
```

This way if the assembly is already loaded into memory, it'll use that one.

Comment: The problem isn't exactly as you described, but it pointed me in the right direction.  My problem is that I am loading two versions of the same file.  One file is in my catch-all folder and the other is in the console app folder.  During development I have been copying files around for the sake of testing.  It seems that I must now get organized.  I think I need to start using the GAC and get closer to my eventual deployed configuration.  Matt, I greatly appreciate your time and effort.